# Add Type Level Natural Numbers

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I assume, that it is not possible to just add two type level natural numbers in haskell. Is this true?

Suppose the natural numbers are defined like so:

```
class HNat a

data HZero
instance HNat HZero

data HSucc n
instance (HNat n) => HNat (HSucc n)
```

Is it pssible to define HAdd in a way similar to:

```
class (HNat n1, HNat n2, HNat ne) => HAdd n1 n2 ne | n1 n2 -> ne
instance             HAdd HZero HZero HZero
instance (HNat x) => HAdd HZero x     x
instance (HNat n1 
         ,HNat x) => HAdd (HSucc n1)  x (HAdd n1 (HSucc x) (???))
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need the case for adding `HZero` and `HZero`. This is already covered by the second case. Think how you'd add Peano naturals on the term level, by induction on the first argument:

```
 data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

 add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
 add Zero     y = y
 add (Succ x) y = Succ (add x y)
```

Now if you're using functional dependencies, you're writing a logic program. So instead of making a recursive call on the right hand side, you add a constraint for the result of the recursive call on the left:

```
 class (HNat x, HNat y, HNat r) => HAdd x y r | x y -> r
 instance (HNat y)     => HAdd HZero     y y
 instance (HAdd x y r) => HAdd (HSucc x) y (HSucc r)
```

You don't need the `HNat` constraints in the second instance. They're implied by the superclass constraints on the class.

These days, I think the nicest way of doing this sort of type-level programming is to use `DataKinds` and `TypeFamilies`. You define just as on the term level:

```
 data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

You can then use `Nat` not only as a type, but also as a *kind*. You can then define a type family for addition on two natural numbers as follows:

```
 type family Add (x :: Nat) (y :: Nat) :: Nat
 type instance Add Zero     y = y
 type instance Add (Succ x) y = Succ (Add x y)
```

This is much closer to the term-level definition of addition. Also, using the "promoted" kind `Nat` saves you from having to define a class such as `HNat`.

Comment: Note that a type family suffices for type-level addition alone, but in order to do term-level calculations that require type-level addition (concatenating fixed-length sequences, for example) you'll generally need a type class as well.

Comment: @C.A.McCann The need for type classes to implement additional functions is independent of the approach taken to implement type-level addition. (I.e., *if* you use a class to implement additional functionality, then you'd need it when using  the `HAdd`-based implementation, too.) Also, I'm not entirely sure why you're saying you need a class in order to implement concatenation fixed-length sequences. When using GADTs, this can easily be done without a class.

Comment: Yeah, that was probably a bad example since the GADT approach is very simple in that case. :] I just wanted to mention that type-level computation alone (by whatever means) doesn't generally let you do term-level computation based on those types without something explicitly connecting the two levels. I've seen people stumble at first because they expect GHC to figure things out for them.

Comment: With regards to your type family example, in Twelf, you can then construct a term that inhabits the type of `Add (Succ Zero) (Succ Zero) (Succ (Succ (Zero)))`, is it possible to do the same in Haskell?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Take a look at the packages `type-level-natural-number` and `` `type-level-natural-number-operations ``. Both are a bit old, but easy to use and the latter defines a `Plus` type family.

Anyway, I would change your last line to something like this (I didn't test if this compiles).

```
instance (HNat n1, HNat x, HAdd n1 x y) => HAdd (HSucc n1) x (HAdd n1 x (HSucc y))
```

Basically, what you do is to define addition inductively and the additional constraint `HAdd n1 x y` adds the necessary inductive case.